# Navigation bar . What I am doing wrong?

Tags: css

OK this is my piece of CSS code .
So I'm trying to replace the white color from the ul(unordered list) with the black color when I'll be hovering over it.Want to mention that I want the text to be black,when I will hover the box of a li and not the anchor.Thanks.

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________
body {
width: 1000px;
font-family: Arial;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
line-height: 135%;
}

.menu ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}


.menu ul li {
display: inline-block;;
padding: 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 1px 0 1px;
border-color:white;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:-5px;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
background-color: white;
color:black;
}

.menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
}

.menu a:hover{
color:black;
}
___________________________________________________________________________


// HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WORKSPACE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you doing wrong? You're not showing us your complete code.

Comment: @Itay is right. Add your HTML or any hosted links.

Comment: the post has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the rule to hover over the `a` element, change the hover state to the `li` and target the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/LUguq/

#### CSS

```
.menu li:hover a{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should access the answer, upvote it, or both

Answer (score 0):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3gNK/)

just add:

```
.menu ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

As you can see in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3gNK/)